# How to update the size of a plotOutput ui object

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to resize a `plotOutput` ui object in shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
        column(6, numericInput('save.height', "Save height (mm)", value = 50)),
        column(6, numericInput('save.width', "Save width (mm)", value = 43))),
  plotOutput('plot_display', width = '50mm', height = '43mm'))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot_display <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
      stat_summary(geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I haven't been able to find something equivalent to `updateNumericInput()` to update the values dynamically in `plotOutput`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the awesome `shinyjqui` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
          jqui_resizabled(plotOutput('hist'))
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(100))
    })
  }
)
```

See here: https://github.com/Yang-Tang/shinyjqui.
[image]

Comment: That's a really cool package, thanks! Is there any way to access the values associated with the plot size when resizing?

Comment: Yes, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068604/use-custom-visual-in-shiny-with-adaptive-constraints/51088656#51088656.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do that you must indicate that the size of your output depends on the value of the input. You can find a working example below :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
 fluidRow(
  column(6, numericInput('save.height', "Save height (mm)", value = 500)),
  column(6, numericInput('save.width', "Save width (mm)", value = 450))),
  plotOutput('plot_display'))

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$plot_display <- renderPlot({

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
  geom_point()

},height = function()input$save.height, width = function()input$save.width)}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```